# Disable specific months JqueryUI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm creating a booking form that includes jQuery UI Datepicker, now i have a main issue that I need help with: Some trips will have only certain days active, and can only be sold certain months because, for example cyclone season.

The function to disable specifc weekdays works perfect, but i'm not sure how can I deactivate complete months for example October. Is it possible?

Any advices will be helpful, here is my code, please let me know if should I explain better my question, or if should I add some other parts of my code. Thanks in advance!

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ getLanguage() ] );

$( "#booking" ).datepicker({
   showOn: "button",
   dateFormat : 'yy/mm/dd',
   buttonText: "Select",
   beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   minDate: 0
}
);

// 0 = monday, 1 = tuesday, 2 = wednesday, 3 = thursday, 4=friday, 5 = saturday, 6=sunday
var daysToDisable = [1, 4, 6];

function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            for (i = 0; i < daysToDisable.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
                    return [false];
                }
            }
            return [true];
 }
```

With this code for example i'm being able to deactivate specific dates, but to deactivate a whole month i'll need to write each date, and in certain cases, i'll need to deactivate at least three or four months for each trip.

```
var $disableMonths = new Array("2013/10/01","2013/10/02","2013/10/03", "...");

function disableSpecificMonths(mydate){
var $return = true;
var $returnclass ="available";

$checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', mydate);

    for(var i = 0; i < $disableMonths.length; i++) {
            if($disableMonths[i] == $checkdate) {
                $return = false;
                $returnclass= "unavailable";
            }
    }

return [$return,$returnclass];

}
```

But also, if it's not possible to deactivate a complete month i'll love to get some ideas on how can I mix this two functions, so i'll be deactivating specific Week Days and Specific Dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update your "disable function" to something like this:

```
var daysToDisable = [1, 4, 6];
var monthsToDisable = [9];

function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }

    var month = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }
    return [true];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it definitely works, but not sure why it deactivates november instead of october. Thoughts?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, the month numbers are counted from 0 to 11, not 1 to 12. I updated the code.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to be counted from 0 to 11 instead of 1 to 12, i'm new on this, and i'd love to learn :)

Comment: it's ok i'm already doing a research about it, thank you so much!

Comment: Also, as you are using `$.inArray`, you don't need the `for` loop, see my updated code.

Comment: thank you so much, it's great that you are always looking to improve your code/answer

Comment: Hi I was wondering if you could help me to join this new function, or please let me know if it will be much better to create a new question here. 

    [link] http://jsfiddle.net/kCdbw/2/

This new function activates only the third friday for every month. But will be great if i'm able to activate it with something like: 

    var specificdaysToDisable = [true or 5 or something];

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do, it would probably be better to create a new question.

Comment: It's ok, I already created that code, but also I added a new question and someone helped me to improve my code. Thanks again for all your help, you're awesome! :)