# I am trying to make my datepicker display only the month of October and the year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker that needs to only show the month of October and allows the user to choose the year. 
I am having a really hard time finding any documentation from the developers on how to make that happen. Right now I only have a datepicker that shows both the month day and year, but I am looking for something more like the one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/5106/). The only difference would be that it would only show October.

This is what I have:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Thank you, in advance, for any help.

Comment: you can try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204707/allow-datepicker-to-show-only-specific-month

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/10234/